# Can id field in django models be the same with two app instances running?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't understand well, how does django's autofield work... If I will run two app instances using gunicorn, will it be possible that my models get same autofield id?
I have a model Message and I want to check it's instance's id, but I want to be absolutly sure, that the ids are unique and are going by adding order.

Comment: Doesn't matter, If you have a User model with pk=1 and an Elephant model with pk=1, Why does it matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id`s are unique for the specific model regardless of if it's within the same app or difference app. The `id` fields are sequential and increments by 1. Even if you delete an object, Django will not replace that ID.

There is no need to add the ID field when creating the model as Django takes care of that by itself.

If you want the `id` to be a unique set of character (for example- instead of the first object `id` being `1`, you want it to be a unique number such as `12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678`), you can use [UUID (Universally Unique Identifier)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html?highlight=uuid#module-uuid). In that case add the following field within your Message model-

Before running the below you would need to remove all migrations of the Message app and older records which still uses the id field.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```